# Docker restarts container every time

Tags: docker, debian, containers

I am just learning Docker, I pulled my first container using:

*docker run -it debian:latest /bin/bash*

After installing some services, like systemd, openssh, etc... I exit the container, using CTRL+D and the next time i start the container (using the same command) I get fresh install of debian without my configs.
I tried using *docker run -it --restart no debian:buster* without success.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: One of the core points of Docker is repeatability. Every time you run `docker run debian`, you'd expect to start with the `debian` image exactly as it's defined, not in some unknown state. You'd typically create a `Dockerfile` and list steps to install stuff to get a custom image into exactly the state that you need. It's not a virtual machine you start and stop and which keeps state.

Comment: I highly recommend to go through this guide https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ Its must read for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out, looks like I am trying to use Docker the wrong way, correct me if I misunderstood something: I need to create a custom Dockerfile in which i need to install my custom image so I can start it from there every time I want, otherwise I am just starting the fresh container pulled from Dockers repositories?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you use

> docker run

command, you create a new container from an existing docker image. With

> docker start $containerName

command, you can start the existing container ($containerName should replace your container real name). Otherwise, to have a custom image of a debian, it is better to write a dockerfile and build an image out of it. Here are the best practices to write a Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: I have a weird issue when I try to start the container with docker start $containerName
When I type the command, all im getting is that "docker start" requers at least 1 argument (I already typed the image ID)

Comment: Can you check if with "docker ps -a" if the container is already created? If it is, then "docker start $containerName" should work. Here $containerName should replace your container name, don't write as i have written here.  Attention with "docker start", you don't type the imageId but the container name.

Comment: I can start the container using Docker exec -it containerName bash successfully!
I now see that I can save all the configs I've made to this container without any problems.
Thank you!